How to correctly extend the React components?
First, please don't try to persuade to use the React Hooks API. I need and want the class API, and that's it.
In below React class component, the PartialsFlags is the associative array-like object which depends on specific inheritor.
import React from "react";


abstract class Gallery<PartialsFlags extends Readonly<{ [key: string]: boolean | undefined; }>>
  extends React.Component<Gallery.Properties<PartialsFlags>>

{

  protected get mustRenderAllPartials(): boolean {
    return Object.values(this.props.partialsFlags).every((value: boolean | undefined): boolean => value === true);
  }

}


namespace Gallery {

  export type Properties<PartialsFlags extends Readonly<{ [key: string]: boolean | undefined; }>> = Readonly<{
    mustVisuallyHideTopHeading: boolean;
    mustVisuallyHideAllHeadings: boolean;
    partialsFlags: PartialsFlags;
  }>;

}

Below component extends the Gallery:
class AdmonitionBlockGallery extends Gallery<AdmonitionBlockGallery.PartialsFlags> {

  public render(): React.ReactNode {
    return <></>;
  }

}


namespace AdmonitionBlockGallery {

  export type PartialsFlags = Readonly<{
    minimal: boolean;
    titles: boolean;
    // ...etc.
  }>;

}

Now if I'll try to use the AdmonitionBlockGallery component:
import AdmonitionBlockGallery from "./_AdmonitionBlockGallery";
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { getExpectedToBeSingleDOM_Element } from "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions-browserjs";
import { isNonEmptyString } from "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions";


const applicationRootElement: HTMLElement = getExpectedToBeSingleDOM_Element({
  selector: "#APPLICATION",
  expectedDOM_ElementSubtype: HTMLElement
});

const hasPartialNameBeenSpecified: boolean = isNonEmptyString(applicationRootElement.dataset.partial_name);

createRoot(applicationRootElement).render(
  <AdmonitionBlockGallery
    mustVisuallyHideTopHeading={ applicationRootElement.dataset.must_visually_hide_top_heading === "" }
    mustVisuallyHideAllHeadings={ applicationRootElement.dataset.must_visually_hide_all_headings === "" }
    partialsFlags={
      {
        minimal:
          !hasPartialNameBeenSpecified || applicationRootElement.dataset.partial_name === "MINIMAL",
          titles:
              !hasPartialNameBeenSpecified || applicationRootElement.dataset.partial_name === "TITLES",
          // ...
      }
    }
  />
);

... I'll get the pretty complicated TypeScript error:
TS2786: AdmonitionBlockGallery cannot be used as a JSX component.

  Its type typeof AdmonitionBlockGallery is not a valid JSX element type.

    Type 'typeof AdmonitionBlockGallery' is not assignable to type 'new (props: any, deprecatedLegacyContext?: any) => Component<any, any, any>'.

      Construct signature return types AdmonitionBlockGallery and Component<any, any, any> are incompatible.

        The types returned by render() are incompatible between these types.

           Type React.ReactNode is not assignable to type
import("D:/***Frontend/FrameworksIntegrations/React/Package/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode

             Type

               ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>

                 is not assignable to type ReactNode

                   Property children is missing in type

                     ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>

                        but required in type ReactPortal


From the viewpoint of JavaScript/JSX, above components are completely valid, and although I have omitted the return value in render method of AdmonitionBlockGallery class, I have checked that components has been rendered correctly.

Ask yourself, is there a simpler way?

React specifically recommends against extending React component classes and relying on composition instead - eg multiple layers of components or components that behave differently based on properties.

@morganney, Thank you for the comment. There are the simple ways, but are there the simple ways without disadvantages? For example, it is possible to stop to use the Gallery class and implement mustRenderAllPartials getter in each class. But what if the common members like mustRenderAllPartials will become, 5? 10? 15?

@morganney, Thank you for the comment. I understand what React recommends, but it does not fit to demand. For example, my UI kit suggests the SearchBox component. Assume that my customer needs almost same one, but 5% of behavior must differ (I don't mean some cosmetic changes like prepended icon). Other customer also needs almost same one, but 10% of behavior must differs. The UI kit can not respect  all of these specific requirements, but the extensions is exactly what need for this case. So, does React recommends the inheritance or no,  it has the demand.

Composition is generally preferable over inheritance, particularly extending multiple classes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance
What tradeoffs you want to make is up to you I guess.

"React.ReactNode is not assignable to type import("…/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode" sounds like you accidentally installed multiple (possibly even different) versions of react

The TS2786: AdmonitionBlockGallery cannot be used as a JSX component error has disappeared once I have updated
"@types/react": "18.0.26"
"@types/react-dom": "18.0.10"

to
"@types/react": "18.3.5"
"@types/react-dom": "18.3.0"


As stated in the comments React usually doesn't use inheritance but that doesn't appear to be the issue here. The issue is with the declared type of that your render function claims to return.
For good explanation of the problem see here. Basically Typescript prior to 5.1 freaks out because React.ReactNode is broader than the expected return type of JSX.Element or React.ReactElement. As not all possible types covered by React.ReactNode contain the property 'children'. Typescript sees this as a potential problem. This has been changed in Typescript newer the 5.1 and should no longer cause a typing error. Element or ReactElement can be used if typescript older than 5.1 needs to be supported.
